# What is "monarchs of the stage"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

Joseph Conrad, "Karain, a Memory":

> His smallest acts were prepared and unexpected, his speeches grave, his sentences ominous like hints and complicated like arabesques. He was treated with a solemn respect accorded in the irreverent West only to the **monarchs of the stage**, and he accepted the profound homage with a sustained dignity seen nowhere else but behind the footlights and in the condensed falseness of some grossly tragic situation.

This is about a ruler in the East called Karain. He is given a lot of respect by his subordinates. Conrad compares such respect with some "monarchs of the stage."

I can't find an explanation of this phrase. Does he mean those ones best on the stage like singers, poets, movie stars (I get it that they've appeared later, it's just an example) or is there a saying like this meaning something else?

Comment: Hello, P. Have you found the phrase in a Google search? Does it seem to be widely used?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hello, Edwin, it finds 12 results, some of them are Conrad's books.

Comment: I'd say it's far from being a fixed expression, then. Conrad's writing is high-flown. Standard nowadays would be _stars of stage and screen_ or probably just _film stars_. I suppose 'famous actors and actresses' would have been necessary around the turn of the century.

Comment: What *are*…, or what does “monarchs…” mean.

Comment: Monarchs means royalty. Metaphorical acting royalty in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the sentence is that the 'irreverent West' doesn't respect great authors, or high religious figures, or great scientists, or real royalty, but only acting celebrities.  So the respect that Karain gets can only be compared to that.